# Pagination using standardsetcontroller not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagination, standardsetcontroller

```
I don't know why the below code is not working , next and previous button.
Any help would be highly appreciated??
VF Page :-
<apex:page controller="paginationcls" >
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageblock>
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!paginateAccts}" var="acc" id="pbt">

       <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}"  />
       <apex:column value="{!acc.Phone}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>     


        <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!GoNext}" reRender="pbt"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!GoPrevious}" reRender="pbt"/>

    </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
Apex Class:-
public class paginationcls {
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon{set;get;}
    public List<Account> paginateAccts{set;get;}
    public paginationcls(){
       setCon= new ApexPages.StandardSetController([select id,name,phone from Account limit 20]); 
          setCon.setPageSize(5); 
        paginateAccts=(List<Account>)setCon.getRecords();
        system.debug(paginateAccts);

    }
    public void GoNext(){
        setCon.next();
     }

    public void GoPrevious(){
        setCon.previous();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never update `paginateAccts`. You need to reset that variable each time you change a page, in the `GoNext()` and `GoPrevious()`. Otherwise, you're simply re-rendering the same list each time.

Comment: ,thnx for ur awesome response but i dont know how to reset the page on calling next method...i dont think any standard method is given in Standardsetcontroller class

Comment: got the answer from your hint...        paginateAccts=(List<Account>)setCon.getRecords();
This line i need to write again in GoNext() method it will work. Let me try it for Previuos method also.

Comment: Thnx David for ur help.